# Entity Framework Combining Strings

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

What would be the best method to concatenate leadTag + content + EndTag into a string for entry into the database?

Here is my data model

```
namespace stories.Models
{
    public class StoryModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }

        public DateTime? date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string leadTag { get; set; }

        public string product { get; set; }

        public string user { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string content { get; set; }

        public string EndTag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want you result string to be in any particular format (e.g. to use a separator between the concatenated strings)?

Comment: A link break would be good but not needed.

Comment: [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx), [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx), [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Could you give an example of desired output?

Comment: The output will essentially be an html page whereas leadtag=<html>, content=<body>, endtag=</html>. Please let me know if any further information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to create another property in your model to combine the data. You could then use that property when writing to the database:

```
public string CombinedProperty
{
    get
    {
        return String.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}", leadTag, content, EndTag);
    }
}
```

Comment: @JGinSD No, It's only 3 out of 8 that are included. Also, OP asks about concatenating those particular fields. What if you overrode `toString` and later added more properties. You could then break the code in other places in a hard to detect way.